# Javascript on invoking on page load

Tags: javascript

I have this script which I would like to invoke when my page loads

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                      window.onload = function() {(function (g, e, n, es, ys) {
                        g['_genesysJs'] = e;
                        g[e] = g[e] || function () {
                          (g[e].q = g[e].q || []).push(arguments)
                        };
                        g[e].t = 1 * new Date();
                        g[e].c = es;
                        ys = document.createElement('script'); ys.async = 1; ys.src = n; ys.charset = 'utf-8'; document.head.appendChild(ys);
                      })(window, 'Genesys', 'https://apps.cloud/gen.min.js', {
                        environment: 'ca',
                        deploymentId: 'abc79173'
                      });
                      Genesys("command", "Database.set", { 
                        messaging: { 
                            customAttributes: { 
                                userLang: "US",
                                CustomerLoggedIn: "false",
                                MainRoute: "Support",
                                SupportArea: "Main",
                                WebURL: window.location.href,
                                }
                            }
                      });
                      Gen('subscribe', 'Journey.ready', () => {
                        Gen('command', 'Journey.trackIdleEvents', { idleEvents: [{ eventName: "idle_for_65sec", idleAfterSeconds: 65 }] });
                    });};
                </script>
```

The issue is the script is loading when I manually place my code in console. But not invoking inserted in the page with window.onload. I have tried both with window.onload and without it. Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong ?

Edit : I am getting error in this line  `g['_genesysJs'] = e;` as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='`

Comment: Try changing `});};` to `})();};` right before `</script>` line

Comment: Tried. Not working.

Comment: is this custom coded or third party provided script ?

Comment: from what i understand, you are trying to load a script dynamically then use that script. If that is the case, you have to wait till the script file is fetched from network.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAkram Thrid party provided script which I need to load on my application

Comment: @AmitKumar do I need to use a timeout function ?

Comment: bind event to your dynamic script tag. like ```ys.addEventListener("load", jsLoaded)```. Then use that library object in ```jsLoaded``` function. you can use anonymous function instead of named one!

Comment: @AmitKumar I have checked. I think the problem is something else. I tried to console log in that script that is also not working when I include my third part script. No errors as well.

Comment: could be that ```load``` event is not getting triggered. check the network tab to see if required script is being fetched. the current url you gave in code above is not valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248249/discussion-between-duck-dragon-and-amit-kumar).